# Excel - VBA - Call path of excel object or current excel.Appliation

Tags: excel, vba, object

[**Cross-posted at MrExcel.com**](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/731077-call-path-active-excel-object.html#)

Any thoughts on how or if it is possible to call the path of an active .xls object?

This code opens and sets the excel object timeXLS
It is a for loop i am using to cycle through a few excel workbooks on my pc

```
Code:

vFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel files (*.xls*),*.xls*", Title:="Please select ", MultiSelect:=True)
If TypeName(vFiles) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub ' Cancelled
Set timeXLS = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
timeXLS.Visible = True
Set R = Worksheets.Add.Range("A1")


  For iFile = LBound(vFiles) To UBound(vFiles)

    timeXLS.Workbooks.Open vFiles(iFile)

    next
```

This syntax I tried calls the path of the generic excel program C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Microsoft Excel

```
Code:
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Range("I" & CurrentRow).Value = timeXLS.Path & "\" & timeXLS.Name
```

This syntax generated debug error 424 ("Object Required" )

```
Code:
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Range("I" & CurrentRow).Value = vFiles(iFile).Path & "\" & vFiles(iFile).Name
```

Any and all advice or assistance on the issue is greatly appreciated and thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Application` 's `.Path` property is not what you want.

YOu have declared `timeXLS` as an instance of `Excel.Application`.

`vFiles(iFile).Path`

`vFiles` is an array/variant, not an object.  Combine the two methods (you're close!) because `.Path` is a member of the `Workbook` object, try instead:

**REVISED**

`... = timeXLS.Workbooks(vFiles(iFile)).FullName`

Comment: Thank you my friend. This has helped greatly.

Comment: The code works however it breaks once the second excel object is set generating a run time error 9 

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Range("I" & CurrentRow).Value = timeXLS.Workbooks(iFile).Name

Comment: `Subscript out of Range` error? Check to make sure that `iFile` variable is a valid workbook name that is open in the `timeXLS` instance.  If it is not, that will certainly fail.  Or, check to make sure that `CurrentRow` value is not 0.

Comment: finally figured out a solution. See tenth post at [link](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/731077-call-path-active-excel-object.html#) 

Thanks again all

Comment: Suggestion not to create a new instance of Excel? Yes, I generally recommend against that, but since you already had the code in place, I just figured that was by design and something you wanted to preserve.

Comment: See my revision. I looked a little closer at the code and think I misinterpreted a thing or two.  If you're trying to print out the path & filename, there's no need to concatenate, since you can just read the file's `FullName` property :)